Associative path Array- Changing setting or variable so new objects appears once grip pulled far enough for that new object length
AutoCAD: Associative path Array:
Im looking to see if any one knows of a setting or variable I can change for my Associative path Array in AutoCAD.

Right now, a new object will appear once I stretch grip JUST far enough past the last object. A new one will pop in.
I am hoping to change something in the settings so that the new object ONLY appears after my grip is far enough in length to accept the new object.

Attached is a description in pictures to help illustrate...
Thanks for any feedback!

